# How to do a distinct count for all individual columns in a pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas, count, distinct

Given a data frame in pandas, how can I return a summary of the distinct count of values for each column? I do not want to hard code the column names as I wish to be able to point the data frame at any CSV or table.

Comment: Hello. In order for the community to be able to help you, it is necessary to identify your difficulty in a specific way. Therefore, it would be interesting for your post to have DATA, and the EXPECTED result. that way users were able to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nunique()` to get the number of distinct elements in the column. I have written a function which will take a dataframe as input and print the columns and the distinct counts.

```
def distCount(df):
        print("Column \t Distinct Count")
        print("====== \t ==============")
        for col in df.columns:
            print(col, "\t", df[col].nunique())
distCount(df)
```

**Output**

```
Column   Distinct Count
======   ==============
Month    12
Sector   10
CWD      11
```